# how to use isset and empty function on multiple values?

Tags: php

I am working on a form through which I want to collect user details. The user will select product size and enter the quantity of that size. I succeeded in assigning the quantity to the corresponding size. But what I failed to do till now is to create an error message if the user has not entered any quantity or selected any size.

How can I check if the size of the file or quantity field is empty?

**The form:**

```
<form method="post" action="">
<fieldset>
    <legend><b>Sizes & Stock</b></legend>
    <p>
Taille : <select name="size[]">
    <option>Choisissez taille</option>
    <option value="unique">Unique</option>
    <option value="45">45</option>
    <option value="43">43</option>
</select>

 Quantite : <input type="text" size="5" name="qty[]" />

 Taille : <select name="size[]">
    <option>Choisissez taille</option>
    <option value="unique">Unique</option>
    <option value="45">45</option>
    <option value="43">43</option>
</select>

 Quantite : <input type="text" size="5" name="qty[]" />
</p>

</fieldset>

<p><input type="submit" name="terminervente" value="Valider la vente"></p>

    </form>
```

**Php code:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['terminervente'])) {

   if (isset($_POST['size']) && ($_POST['qty'])) {

     foreach ($_POST['size'] as $cle => $val) {

        foreach ($_POST['qty'] as $kq => $vq) {
        $found = false;
         if ($cle == $kq) {
          $found = true;
           $test []= array('sizes'=>$val, 'quantity'=>$vq);
         }
      }

     }

      print_r($test);
  }


}
```

Comment: the short answer, yes

Comment: you have to write `if(isset($_POST['qty']))` or `($_POST['qty']) = "some value"` instead of `($_POST['qty'])`

Comment: @SaggingRufus : i dont get your comment..

Comment: you asked if you could make the code check the quantity the answer is yes you can

Comment: if $_POST['qty'] != '' ..... else error qty not set

Comment: @SaggingRufus : i was asking, how i can check if the qty field is empty...i have tried...if(isset($_POST['qty'])  && !empty($_POST['qty'] ) ) ....but not working..it is like the $_POST['qty'] has always a value..even if no value is entered in the qty field.